# I am trying to record a video using a service

Tags: android

i am trying to develop an application which records a video for a certian time in the background and then stops automatically. I am able to initialize all the necessary things but not able to record it

My main actiVity:

```
 mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(StartTestActivity.this,
                RecorderService.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startService(intent);
        finish();
```

My RecorderService:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class RecorderService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "RecorderService";
private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
private static Camera mServiceCamera;
private boolean mRecordingStatus;
private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mRecordingStatus = false;
    mServiceCamera = Camera.open(1);
    mSurfaceView = MainActivity.mSurfaceView;
    mSurfaceHolder = MainActivity.mSurfaceHolder;
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    if (mRecordingStatus == false)
        startRecording();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopRecording();
    mRecordingStatus = false;

    super.onDestroy();
}

public boolean startRecording() {
    try {
        Camera.Parameters params = mServiceCamera.getParameters();
        mServiceCamera.setParameters(params);
        Camera.Parameters p = mServiceCamera.getParameters();

        final List<Size> listSize = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Size mPreviewSize = listSize.get(2);
        Log.v(TAG, "use: width = " + mPreviewSize.width
                + " height = " + mPreviewSize.height);
        p.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        p.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP);
        mServiceCamera.setParameters(p);

        try {
            mServiceCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            mServiceCamera.startPreview();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mServiceCamera.unlock();

        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mServiceCamera);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/vid
eo.mp4");
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mPreviewSize.width, 
mPreviewSize.height);
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(5000);
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        mMediaRecorder.start();
        mRecordingStatus = true;
        return true;
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public void stopRecording() {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Recording Stopped",     
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try {
        mServiceCamera.reconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mMediaRecorder.stop();
    mMediaRecorder.reset();
    mServiceCamera.stopPreview();
    mMediaRecorder.release();
    mServiceCamera.release();
    mServiceCamera = null;
}
}
```

My errors:

```
08-20 11:10:54.184  12603-12603/com.example.svbhargav.mediafilesharing 
E/MediaRecorder﹕ start failed: -19
08-20 11:10:54.189  12603-12603/com.example.svbhargav.mediafilesharing  
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.svbhargav.mediafilesharing, PID: 12603
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service 
com.example.svbhargav.mediafilesharing.RecorderService@32ef1113 with Intent 
{ flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.svbhargav.mediafilesharing/.RecorderService 
}: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
        at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2942)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:154)
        at     
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1419)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at 

 .android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
 (ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
        at   
 com.example.svbhargav.mediafilesharing.RecorderService.startRecording
 (RecorderService.java:114)
  com.example.svbhargav.mediafilesharing.RecorderService.onStartCommand
 (RecorderService.java:45)
        at .ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2925)     
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:154)
```

Comment: You can't do UI related stuff in your Service. Do not use a Service for that.

Comment: its happening is background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done similar stuffs and get success also you can also go through below link 
[Background video recording in Android 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049041/background-video-recording-in-android-4-0)