# Camera freezes on phone sleep/wake

Tags: android, android-camera

I am building a custom video recorder, and noticing that if the phone goes into sleep or lock mode while the camera activity is running.. upon wake up the camera preview is stuck on a static still image.  if I go back and forth between activities the camera is fine upon return.. this bug is apparently only when the phone goes to sleep and wakes up.

**my video recorder activity**

```
public class DRPVideoCaptureActivity extends Activity {

    private Camera myCamera;
    private DRPCameraSurfaceView myCameraSurfaceView;
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;

    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    boolean recording = false;

    Globals g = new Globals();
    ImageButton btn_record;
    FrameLayout _videoView;

    ImageView btn_flashToggle;
    ImageView btn_cameraToggle;
    ImageView btn_close;

    public enum FlashState {
        off, on, auto
    }

    FlashState _flashState = FlashState.off;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_camera);

        _videoView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.video_frame);
        btn_record = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_record);
        btn_flashToggle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_flash_toggle);
        btn_cameraToggle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_camera_toggle);
        btn_close = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
        recording = false;


        // myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Get Camera for preview
        _videoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        myCamera = getCameraInstance();
        if (myCamera == null) {
            Toast.makeText(DRPVideoCaptureActivity.this, "Fail to get Camera",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{

            myCameraSurfaceView = new DRPCameraSurfaceView(this, myCamera);
            _videoView.addView(myCameraSurfaceView);
        }

        _videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    Button.OnClickListener recordListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (recording) {
                // stop recording and release camera
                mediaRecorder.stop(); // stop the recording
                releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object

                // Exit after saved
                finish();
            } else {

                // Release Camera before MediaRecorder start
                releaseCamera();

                if (!prepareMediaRecorder()) {
                    Toast.makeText(DRPVideoCaptureActivity.this,
                            "Fail in prepareMediaRecorder()!\n - Ended -",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }

                mediaRecorder.start();
                recording = true;
                // myButton.setText("STOP");
            }
        }
    };

    private Camera getCameraInstance() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Camera c = null;
        try {

            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
            c.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("cam","EXCEPTION: "+e);// Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {
        myCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        myCamera.unlock();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);

        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
                .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(g.kExtStorageDirectory + g.kVideoDirectory
                + "myvideo.mp4");
        mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
        mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Set max file size 5M

        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(myCameraSurfaceView.getHolder()
                .getSurface());

        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseMediaRecorder(); // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it
                                // first
        releaseCamera(); // release the camera immediately on pause event

    }

    private void releaseMediaRecorder() {
        if (mediaRecorder != null) {
            mediaRecorder.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
            mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mediaRecorder = null;
            myCamera.lock(); // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (myCamera != null) {
            myCamera.stopPreview();

            myCamera.release(); // release the camera for other applications
            myCamera = null;
        }
    }

}
```

**my camera surface view**

```
public class DRPCameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public DRPCameraSurfaceView(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int weight,
            int height) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
          // preview surface does not exist
          return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
          // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        this.getHolder().removeCallback(this);
        //mCamera.stopPreview();
       // mCamera.release();
       // mCamera = null;
        Log.v("surfaceDestroyed", "surfaceDestroyed");


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well you are trying to build application that able to record from background
for that you must take help of service in android 
and one more think if your camera currently running in background from your application and another application when trying to access camera but it occupy by your application then it will be cause crash that app for your advice be careful

refer this link for video record from background : [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121660/how-to-record-video-from-background-of-application-android)

Comment: its not crashing.. the camera preview is just still

Comment: i m just giving you advice manh that if you will not release camera from you application then other app which want to use camera will crash.. just for your knowledge friend ..

Comment: and for your solution you should attach video recording code in service so it will run in background. for more information about service in android find here. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html