# How to Record Video from Background Service using Camera2 API?

Tags: android, android-service, android-camera2

I am trying to record video from a Background Service without showing any preview. It is like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121660/how-to-record-video-from-background-of-application-android) but trying to do it with Camera2 API.

I am trying to follow along with the [android-Camera2Video sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video) and trying to use that in the service.

Which parts should I cut out / ignore - is it the part `TexttureViewer` part where it is previewed? I dont want to preview anything I just want to record it.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Did you find any solution?