# Android Face Detection on the background

Tags: java, android, face-detection

I'm making an app where I want to detect user's face without showing it. I use standart android api which is `android.hardware.Camera.faceDetection()` When front camera sees the face, the phone vibrate. I've already implemented this part and now I need to make this app work on the background, so it shouldn't be preview shown on screen. Is it possible?

Comment: what are you trying to do ? some spy app ? be aware that google play store will check for it and maybe with the T.O.S you will not be able to launch it in the store

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to record video from background of application : Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121660/how-to-record-video-from-background-of-application-android)

Comment: @IDroid No, of course not a spy app, everything is ok

Comment: @PavloKovalov were you able to achieve that . As i have same requirements for my app and looking for a solution .

Comment: @SohailYasin no, unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is for the Background Worker.
You can add your code in `doInBackground()`.
It will execute your all processes in the background.
Hope it will help full to you.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Background extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected void done(){
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Process Done Successfully...","Successfull",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        //Write your code here
        return null;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn’t think that it so easy, I thought I always have to show preview to make face detection work, that’s why I asked, thank you again!!!

Comment: It's okay, Your welcome.